# Regex Help - Directory from a url

Tags: regex, perl

I have the urls like the following.

```
<a href="http://cdn1.xyz.com/testone/2010/a.jpg">
<a href="http://cdn2.xyz.com/testtwo/2010/a.jpg">
```

I want to extract the first part of the url. For ex: http://cdn1.xyz.com/testone or http://cdn2.xyz.com/testtwo. What is the regular expression which matches that format.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't there a CPAN module to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($string =~ m{([^:]+://[^/]+/[^/]+)}) {
  print $1;
} else {
  print 'no match';
}
```

Can also try this.

Comment: Missing backwhacks.  To make a regex like this readable, use a different delimiter like `m{...}`.  Also, avoid using $& as it will slow down every regex in the process as Perl has to capture and hang onto the match whether or not you'll use it (though the penalty is not as bad as it used to be).  Use capturing parens instead.

Comment: Very nice -- terse and comprehensive.

Comment: @Schwern, I'll delete my post if you post a solution.  I never mastered perl.  Sounds like you know a lot more.

Comment: Don't delete it, your solution is basically fine for a regex.  You've constructed it as a good catch-all to avoid being caught by non-ASCII URLs.  Just switch it to use capturing.  `m{(...your regex...)}` and then use $1 instead of $&.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to pull the links out of HTML, use something like [HTML::SimpleLinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aSimpleLinkExtor) to handle that part.

URLs are subtly complicated things and getting more complicated.  The regex you use will inevitably be wrong.  You can use the URI module to parse the URL and then modify it.

```
use URI;
my $uri = URI->new($url_string);
```

Now that we have the $uri as an object we can get just the path part and change that to chop off anything we don't want.

```
# Get the path already split into pieces
my @path = $uri->path_segments;

# Put just the first bit back, also clear the query 
$uri->path_query($path[0]);

# clear any "#foo" it might have
$uri->fragment(undef);
```

And now $uri is what you want.  Its string overloaded, so you can just use $uri as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$url =~ m{([^:]*://.*?\.[a-z]*?/[^/]*)/.*};
```

I might suggest looking for regexp modules that match on URLs. It's a common enough and sometimes difficult task that some packages out there probably do a really good job with. If your needs are really simple and you can guarantee url simplicity though I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Can't count on alpha numeric domain names any more.  Or that its a .com.

Comment: This is bad in so many ways (explicit protocol, explicit domain, incomplete charset for URL)-- won't downvote though, too small rep :)

Comment: @Schwern @Nick: Thanks for pointing that out, just edited the post a little. I made some assumptions given the OP's examples. How's that?

Comment: That is an unreadable mess known as "leaning toothpick syndrome".  Use a different delimiter like `m{...}`, get rid of the backwacks and then I'll read it. ;P  I can note that even TLDs don't have to be alpha any more.

Comment: @Schwern: Better? It still only takes alpha TLDs though. But I learned about m{ }, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not too good but works well

```
$url='<a href="http://cdn1.xyz.com/testone/2010/a.jpg">';
$url =~ m|(\w+)://([^/:]+)(:\d+)?/(.*)|;
$aa=$4;
($aa)=split('\/',$aa);
$wanted=$1.'://'.$2.'/'.$aa;
print $wanted;
```

Pints `http://cdn1.xyz.com/testone`